# "LOAD" is not valid at this position for server version..." // Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I'm a total newbie in SQL and I'm having a hard time to look for answers that are the same with my case. I was trying to follow a video tutorial about loading data in mySQL, but when I typed these following commands:

```
LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Given\\Documents\\exercise' into table pop_proj Fields terminated by ',' Enclosed by '"' Lines terminated by '\n' Ignore 1 lines;
```

I got the following error message:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'LOCAL DATA INFILE
>   'C:\Users\Given\Documents\exercise' into table pop_proj

I don't know what checking the manual that corresponds to my server means.
I'd really appreciate if someone can help me out on this. Sorry for being noob. Thanks.

Comment: You have to follow the syntax.  You can't just write whatever, and expect it to work.

Comment: Look `@@secure_file_priv` value. PS. LOCAL makes no sense for local device.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of the `LOAD DATA` statement is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ... INTO TABLE ...
```

Instead of:

```
LOAD LOCAL DATA INFILE ... INTO TABLE ...
```

Reference: [MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)